# Best way to remove empty keys from a FormData object?

Tags: javascript, form-data

I'm constructing an Ajax request using FormData and I can't find an accepted way to eliminate empty keys.

I wrote my own way to do it but I'm wondering, is there a way to do it with no iterator, or a more efficient way to iterate it?

```
let payload = new FormData(document.querySelector('#form'));
[...payload.entries()].forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (value == 0) payload.delete(key);
});
```

I expect a lot of calls to this particular function so every bit of optimization helps.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to avoid an iterator if you want to filter the entire `FormData` object because `FormData` will always return an object with key/value pairs.

If you can use the recent JS for things (or at least relatively recent stuff), the simplest/readable version is probably going to use Array.filter(). Something like the following.

```
let data = Array
   .from(new FormData(document.querySelector('#form')))
   .filter(function([k, v]) { return v });
```

`Array.from()` is used to coerce the object into an Array prototype so you can use `filter()` on it. But you could just as easily use your current Array coercion on it.

One nice thing about using Filter, instead of current one is that Filter will return a new Array with the cleaned up data, rather than mutating the current payload like you are currently doing.

MDN Reference Links

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  A very nice first answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do is to use the native tools available for [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object:

> An object implementing `FormData` can directly be used in a `for...of` structure, instead of `entries()`: `for (const p of myFormData)` is equivalent to `for (const p of myFormData.entries())`.

Also IMO below example is more readable.

```js
let payload = new FormData(document.querySelector('#form'));

for (let [key, value] of payload.entries())
{
   if (value === '') payload.delete(key);
}
```